# For Statement Issue?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, bukkit

So I have this bit of code and I'm having problems with my for loop.

```
@EventHandler
    public void onPistonExtend(BlockPistonExtendEvent event)
    {
        if (TownStones.blockPistons)
        {
            List<Block> pushedBlocks = event.getBlocks();
            Material theMaterial = null;
            int end = TownStones.blocks;
            boolean done = false;
            if (pushedBlocks != null) {
                for (Iterator localIterator = pushedBlocks.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext(); !done)
                {
                    Block theBlock = (Block)localIterator.next();
                    theMaterial = theBlock.getType();
                    done = false;
                    int i = 0; continue;
                    if (theMaterial == Material.getMaterial(TownStones.blockType[i]))
                    {
                        event.setCancelled(true);
                        done = true;
                    }
                    else if (i > end)
                    {
                        done = true;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Intellij Idea is telling me `!done` is not a Statement

Comment: `for (initialization; termination; increment)`

Comment: That's because IntelliJ is right. You know what's supposed to go into the last part of a `for` loop, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `!done` isn't a statement. The issue is your for loop:

```
for (Iterator localIterator = pushedBlocks.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext(); !done)
```

This reads as "to begin, declare `localIterator` and set it to `pushedBlocks.iterator()`, then continue while the iterator has more elements". There's no semantic meaning to `!done`. Rewrite the for loop as:

```
for (Iterator localIterator = pushedBlocks.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext() && !done;)
```

Answer (score 2):

A Java `for` loop must conform to the

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

style. `!done` is not a valid increment statement. Please refer to
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html
for an introduction on how to use a `for` loop.